# How to automatically get fps meter value from chrome developer tools with code or an API?

Tags: google-chrome, frame-rate

Is there any API or some code that I can use to get the value of fps meter in developer tools? 
We want to measure the web performance in webgl canvas with automation, and we tried stats and requestAnimationFrame, but the fps value is different from fps meter in chrome developer tools ->rendering->fps meter. and we think fps meter better measures the fps value.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/

**Usage:**

Copy source files to your folder then add script in `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/stats.js"></script>
```

then call stats();

```
var stats = new Stats();
stats.showPanel( 1 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );

function animate() {

    stats.begin();

    // monitored code goes here

    stats.end();

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

}

requestAnimationFrame( animate );
```

Comment: have you used it? How reliable is it?